# SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: double precision > interval

Tags: laravel, postgresql

So I'm using Laravel with GraphQL and PostgreSQL database.

My query is very long, but more specifically this line

```
selectRaw('(CASE
                WHEN (COALESCE(((NULLIF((project_members.hourly_rate - last_known_user_costs.cost), 0)/NULLIF(project_members.hourly_rate, 0)) * 100),0) > (
                        SELECT value :: INTERVAL FROM "configuration" WHERE "key" = \'Gross Margin Per Resource Yellow\'
                )) THEN \'red\'
                WHEN (COALESCE(((NULLIF((project_members.hourly_rate - last_known_user_costs.cost), 0)/NULLIF(project_members.hourly_rate, 0)) * 100),0) > (
                        SELECT value :: INTERVAL FROM "configuration" WHERE "key" = \'Gross Margin Per Resource Green\'
                )) THEN \'green\'
                ELSE \'red\'
            END) AS status')
```

when added, throws the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision > interval\nLINE 2: ...t), 0)/NULLIF(project_members.hourly_rate, 0)) * 100),0) > (\n                                                                    ^\nHINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I don't know if I'm writing the sentence properly

Comment: The error is pretty specific the left side of the `>` operator is `double precision`(float) and the right side is an `interval` and `>` does not support that. What is the data type for the field `value` and why are you converting it to an `interval`? Add answer as update to question.

Comment: Figured it out, turns out the type should have been double precision instead of interval, thanks!